# What percentage of newly created bitcoins have never been moved?

Tags: mining-reward, money-supply

As of today, what number of coinbases, what number of coins, and therefore what percentage of the newly created coins have never been moved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of block 445550 (december 28, 2016, 19:14 UTC), there are 55450 blocks with unspent coinbase outputs, with a combined value of 1854952.32263065 BTC.